# Error when I tried to run flutter doctor --android-licenses

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, I installed it on my Ubuntu,
on running flutter doctor I got error
*Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
✗ Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
more details.*

So I tried
flutter doctor flutter doctor --android-licenses, which gave me this error

*Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
*

someone please let me know what I should do. I tried downgrading jdk'11 to jdk'8 didnt work

Comment: Have you installed Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few minutes of finding whats happening with licenses, I rebooted my system after downgrading the jdk and It worked.

Sometimes we just need to reboot :)